# Print Latitude and longitude in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

> I am new in flutter, I am working on solving bugs in app. I want to print latitude and longitude of current user after 2 seconds, how can i do that?

```
void startTimer() {
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 2);
    timer2 = new Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) {
        if (start == 0) {
          timer.cancel();
          setState(() {});
          // });
        } else {
          // setState(() {
          start--;
          setState(() {
            print("My current location ${homeMapCtrl!.userCurrentLatLng}");
          });
          // });
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

> I am using this method and i am calling it in Consumer but it always run upto 1 to 100 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `Future.delayed`

```dart
void startTimer() async{
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));  

    print("My current location ${homeMapCtrl!.userCurrentLatLng}");
```

Comment: Not printing anything :(

Comment: At least you are supposed to get `My current location` even if the value is null. Are you calling  `startTimer()`?

Comment: yup i was calling the function in init but it is only showing for 10 seconds i need to print it continuously

Comment: when   the timer will stop?

Answer (score 0):

Use location package to get user location or you can checkout this link for example [click here](https://github.com/Sahil-Atahar/Flutter-Mini-Project-Flutter-Location)